# iphone, itunes store app: how to view text hidden by "..."

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes-store

I just went to look at the next album by Tune Yards and I can see it says "Pre Order: expected J..." but there appears to be no way to view this text!

Anyone know how to expand it or get it show the full text

I've seen the non expandable "..." before and it's annoyed me enough over time to post :)

Answer (score 1):

One way to view the full text is to tap on the Share icon at top right of the screen and then tap on one of the options such as the Message icon. Doing this will create a new Message with the full text followed by the URL. You can then just cancel the message, or send it to yourself!

Obviously, this is really just a workaround I use because I haven't come across another way within iOS to view the full text.